# A bound on characteristic functions: $|\phi(t)|\leq 1-\frac{1-c^2}{8b^2}t^2$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, characteristic-functions

> Let $\phi$ be the characteristic function of some probability distribution, $0<b$ and $0<c<1$. Suppose $|t|\geq b \implies |\phi(t)|\leq c$. Prove that $|t|<b \implies |\phi(t)|\leq 1-\frac{1-c^2}{8b^2}t^2$

This is from a qualifying exam, with no hints. I can't make progress on this one and I'd appreciate any hint or suggestion.

Comment: Do you know the following result...? If $\varphi$ is a characteristic function such that $|\phi(t_0)| \geq 1- c |t_0|^2$ for some $c>0$ and $t_0$, then $|\phi(n t_0)| \geq 1- c |n t_0|^2$ for all $n \geq 1$.

Comment: @saz No, I don't know this lemma

Comment: Interesting question. One should enlarge the scope by looking for corresponding results in harmonic analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step is to prove the following auxiliary result:

> **Lemma** For any characteristic function $\phi$ it holds that $$1- |\phi(2t)|^2 \leq 4 (1-|\phi(t)|^2), \qquad t \in \mathbb{R}.\tag{1}$$

Proof: Let $f$ be a real-valued characteristic function and denote by $\mu$ the associated probability measure. Clearly, $$1-f(t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} (1-\cos(tx)) \, d\mu(x), \qquad t \in \mathbb{R}.$$ Using that

$$1-\cos(y) = 2 \sin^2 \left( \frac{y}{2} \right) \tag{2}$$

and

$$|\sin(2y)| = 2 |\sin y \cos y| \leq 2 |\sin y| \tag{3}$$

we find

$$\begin{align*} 1- \cos(tx) \stackrel{(2)}{=} 2 \sin^2 \left( \frac{tx}{2} \right) &\stackrel{(3)}{\geq} \frac{1}{2} \sin^2 (tx) \stackrel{(2)}{=} \frac{1}{4} (1-\cos(2tx)). \end{align*}$$ Integrating both sides with respect to $\mu$ yields $$1-f(2t) \leq 4 (1-f(t)), \qquad t \in \mathbb{R}.$$ Applying this inequality to $f(t) = |\phi(t)|^2$ proves the assertion. (I leave it to you to check that this is indeed a characteristic function.)

---

Iterating $(1)$, we find

$$1-|\phi(2^n t)|^2 \leq 4^n (1-|\phi(t)|^2) \tag{4}$$

for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. For any $t \neq 0$, $|t|<b$ we can choose $n$ such that $2^{-n} b \leq |t| < 2^{-n+1} b$. Then, by assumption, $|\phi(2^n t)|^2 \leq c^2$ and therefore

$$1-c^2 \leq 1-|\phi(2^n t)|^2 \stackrel{(4)}{\leq} 4^n (1-|\phi(t)|^2).$$

By the very choice of $n$, we have $2^n \leq 2b/|t|$. Hence,

$$1-c^2 \leq 4 \frac{b^2}{t^2} (1-|\phi(t)|^2),$$

i.e. $$|\phi(t)|^2 \leq 1- \frac{(1-c^2)}{4b^2} t^2.$$

Finally, we use the elementary inequality

$$\sqrt{1-C t^2} \leq 1- \frac{Ct^2}{2}$$

which holds for any constant $C>0$ to conclude that

$$|\phi(t)| \leq \sqrt{1- \frac{1-c^2}{4b^2} t^2} \leq 1- \frac{1-c^2}{8b^2} t^2.$$

Comment: [+1] Very interesting. Do you have references for these type of inequalities. Are these results connected to a larger "theory" in Harmonic Analysis ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Not sure about the connection to harmonic analysis. There are several books which discuss inequalities for characteristic functions; the one which I like most is the book by Ushakov ("Selected topics on characteristic functions"); it contains a whole chapter on inqualities.

Comment: It's nice, but quite out of the blue...

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM well, if you find a nicer/more intuitive proof, then let me know.