# for characteristic function $\phi$, prove that $1-|\phi(2u)|^2\le 4( 1-|\phi(u)|^2 )$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, generating-functions

I know that, If $X$ and $Y$ are two independent random variables then $$\phi_{X+Y}(u) =\phi_{X}(u)\cdot\phi_{Y}(u)$$
and

$ \phi_{-X}(u)=\overline{\phi_{X}(u)}$

How to proceed further?any steps to the right direction would be helpful.

Comment: See the first part of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2214271/36150)

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3099598/36150)